# Does skeletron prime have more defence with the limbs alive?

Tags: terraria

I've hard this question for a while I was playing Terraria with my friend and we fought skeletron prime and regular skeletron he said that the boss had more defense with the limbs is this true?

Answer (score 1):

No, Skeletron Prime does not have more defense while its limbs are alive. This is a common misconception, as the limbs intercept attacks and take the damage instead of the head, leading to the illusion that Skeletron Prime has more defense when the limbs are flailing around.

The only time Skeletron Prime has a higher defense is when its head begins spinning.

Focusing on the limbs is an advisable strategy, as it reduces the risk of you taking more damage, and allows you to damage the head more accurately.